# Javascript Chat Color

Tags: javascript, window, chat

So I have been working with a Javascript chat script. I had made a style for it, and made the basic chat. I then decided to add a few commands with the window.commands attribute. Most of them worked. If you typed `/afk` then it would say you were afk. I had multiple commands, and I wanted to add one more. I wanted to make it so that if the person typed `/color` it would say, while in the color green.

> Hello World!

However, when I ran it, nothing happened, and as a matter of fact, the rest of the commands didn't work.

For more information on the issue, please look at the code snippits below.

chat.js - Commands

```
window.commands = {
```

Chat.js - Color Command

```
'color':  function(com,text) {
            $('#Write[name="message"]').val('Hello World!' + text.fontcolor["green"]);
        },
```

The command it's self is fine, I know this because when I would remove the `text.fontcolor["green"]` it would say Hello World in the default chat color.

Which means it is something with setting the color, I am not sure if a variable needs to be set first. Or maybe I am using a completely wrong thing for this case.

And that's where I am at a loss.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but what it `text` object?

Comment: And an input field does not normally take a value of something in color. A div or span could take $("#outputDiv").html("Hello").css({color:"green"});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to change the css of the field instead:

```
$('#Write[name="message"]').css('color', text.fontcolor["green"]);
```

And then change the font color of the chat entry in the chat itself too.